# Check for a valid Facebook Session

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I was just checking for the state of FBSession

```
- (BOOL)hasValidSession {
    return (self.session.state == FBSessionStateOpen)
 }
```

Occasionally the state would briefly be changed to FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended and this would return NO which would bring down my login modal. When I would click connect again it would crash the app for trying to reestablish an active facebook session. So I changed it to

```
- (BOOL)hasValidSession {
if (self.session.state == FBSessionStateOpen || self.session.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}}
```

My above method works so far but it seems like a hack... What is the best ubiquitous way to check for a valid session in your app?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I check the facebook session in my app and it works for me:

```
-(BOOL)checkFacebookSession
{
    if([FBSession activeSession].state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Logged in to Facebook");
        [self openFacebookSession];
        UIAlertView *alertDialog;

        alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"You're already logged in to Facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertDialog show];

        [alertDialog release];
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not logged in to Facebook");
        return NO; //Show login flow.
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: what action to perform here [self openFacebookSession];

Answer (score 0):

The session is active if the state is either in `FBSessionStateOpen` or in `FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended`. You can use the method below to get the current status of the user is logged in:

```
- (BOOL)isActiveSession
{
    return (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen 
           || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended);
}
```